# Find and replace within an associated Array

Tags: php, arrays

So I have an associated array that returns search engine results, it returns a url,title and snippet for each result,
 I want to find an replace all instances of "http:// and www." from the beginning of each of the urls. This is what I've tried so far, it spits out the url,title and snippet but it doesn't replace the "http:// and www.",

```
<?php
foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
    {   
        $blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = ($item->{'url'});         
        $blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = ($item->{'url_title'});
        $blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});
        $i++;
    }

    $find = array ('http://','www.');
    $replace = array ('','');

    $new_blekkoArray = str_replace ($find, $replace, $blekkoArray);

    print_r ($new_blekkoArray); 
?>
```

I'm a bit of a noob at php can anyone help.
Regards from Ireland

Comment: str_replace can take an array, but it does not traverse down into sub-arays, e.g. it works with a SINGLE level of an array at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$find = array ('http://','www.');

foreach ($js->RESULT as $item)
{   
        $blekkoArray[$i]['url'] = str_replace ($find, '', ($item->{'url'}) );         
        $blekkoArray[$i]['title'] = ($item->{'url_title'});
        $blekkoArray[$i]['snippet'] = ($item->{'snippet'});

        $i++;
}

print_r ($blekkoArray);
```

Comment: Suggest doing the replacement during the initial assignment to `$blekkoArray[$i]['url']`.

Comment: and also declaring $find, $replace outside foreach loop.

Comment: @Maximus2012 All fair recommendations.

Comment: you can probably do away with $i index variable too since its numeric array, the loop iteration will take care of that part.

Comment: $replace doesn't have to be an array... can just be an empty string

Comment: and its worth noting that this will replace all occurances of the string in the url... not just at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Top man Wayne, that worked perfectly, thanks to everyone else for the added suggestions and explanations.